# How to ensure nvidia_current module loads during boot

Tags: nvidia, 12.10

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 on an Asus G75V laptop with nvidia gforce GTX 660M. I first run 12.04 on this machine and was able to install nvidia_current drivers from swat ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

This worked in 12.04 and after rebooting the machine my graphics where working properly. After upgrade to 12.10 however, the machine boots into a low resolution desktop which I can not really interact with. I suspect this is due to the driver not being loaded properly. To fix this, I have to switch to `ctrl+alt+F1` session and manually load the nvidia_current module and restart the desktop manager:

```
sudo modprobe nvidia_current
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Now everything works fine again. However, I would like not to have to do this every time I reboot the machine. I also dont want to hack an script to do this on load. Basically, if things are setup currectly, the nvidia_current driver which is installed should load. How can I make sure nvidia_current driver module loads properly when system starts?

**Edit:** I tried removing the ppa and installing `nvidia-current-update` as was suggested in the comments. However, I still face the same problem. The only difference is that now when I restart I come back to desktop with this distorted image:

[image]

It appears that nvidia module is not being loaded properly when system boots, even though working drivers are installed.

Again, to work around this issue I can switch to `ctrl+alt+F1` session and login. Then I can run this code to get the driver loaded and the desktop back:

```
sudo modprobe nvidia_current_updates
sudo service lightdm restart
```

I thought it may be that nvidia_current_updates is somehow being blacklisted somewhere or that nouveau driver is not being blacklisted. So I went into /etc/modprobe.d directory and take a look around. I could not find any evidence of that. Here is the content of `nvidia-graphic-drivers.conf` which seems relevant:

```
:/etc/modprobe.d$ cat nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf 
# This file was installed by nvidia-current-updates
# Do not edit this file manually

blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
blacklist nvidia-173
blacklist nvidia-96
blacklist nvidia-current
blacklist nvidia-173-updates
blacklist nvidia-96-updates
alias nvidia nvidia_current_updates
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
```

Comment: I don't see any packages for Quantal in that PPA. Try removing it with `sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`, and then install `nvidia-current-updates` from the Drivers Utility. That should set it up properly.

Comment: when I try the I get an error that ppa-purge is not a command: `sudo: ppa-purge: command not found`. Looks like I need to install pps-purge. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Install it first: `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`.

Comment: I tried this suggestion, however nvidia_current_updates module behaves the same way and is not loading properly when I reboot the machine. Please see my updated question.

Comment: You could try adding `nvidia_current_updates` to /etc/modules to ensure autoloading. If that doesn't work, check your Xorg.0.log.

Comment: @mikewhatever thanks for this suggestion. That did solve the issue. Feel free to put that down as answer.

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates` PPA currently doesn't have any packages for Quantal, I'd suggest removing it.

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

Then install the recommended or experimental Nvidia driver. You can make sure the module loads by adding it to /etc/modules.